# Separating large file and inserting carriage returns based on string

Tags: vb.net, carriage-return

New to VB.Net but a friend recommended that I used it for what I'm trying to do. I have a huge text file and I want to insert carriage returns in after a specific string.

Apart from the mess I have below , how would I alter this to read a file and then once we see the text "ext" insert a new line feed. I'm expecting one of the lines in the input file to produce alot of carriage returns.

Currently what I have managed to mock together below reads an input file until end of line and writes it out again into another file.

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Try
        ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file. 
        ' The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\My Documents\input.txt")
            Dim line As String
            ' Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
            ' the file is reached. 

            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\My Documents\output.txt")
                Do Until sr.EndOfStream
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                    Console.WriteLine("done")
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch e As Exception
        ' Let the user know what went wrong.
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Changes made following comments.. Falling over at 500mb files due to memory constraints:

```
    Sub Main()
    Try
        ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file. 
        ' The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\My Documents\input.txt")
            Dim line As String
            Dim term As String = "</ext>"
            ' Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
            ' the file is reached. 

            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\My Documents\output.txt")
                Do Until sr.EndOfStream
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                    line = line.Replace(term, term + Environment.NewLine)
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                    Console.WriteLine("done")
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: You should write to a different file than the one you are reading from. Regarding what you want, it should be enough with `Replace` and `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: @varocarbas - Replace is not so simple as what will happen if the string contains the words NEXT, TEXT, EXTENTION etc... the replace will work in all these situations.

Comment: @Mych Logically. You have to take care of your specific conditions. I have just given some hints about how to face the problem with VB.NET. You might complement it with a loop systematically redefining the string. For example: "this is the first ext-asda version of extention asdfas"... converted into "-asda version of extention asdfas" after the first analysing and into "ention asdfas" after the second one. But the OP has to do some effort by his own; not the case in the posted code, which doesn't take care of that issue at all.

Comment: @varocarbas - don't get me wrong... I realise that you were giving a pointer... I was just wanted to add that there was more to do then just use Replace.

Comment: @Mych how are you sure there is more to do? Based on his question, the only thing to do is add a new line after the text ext

Comment: Derek - I am falling over at 500mb files with running out of memory. And that is one of my medium sized files. Updated the question with changes I made following comments. works on smaller sized files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your lines are very big, you'll have to:

- Read/Write one character at a time
- Save the last x characters
- If the last x characters are equal to your term, write a new line

  ```
  Dim term As String = "</ext>"
  Dim lastChars As String = "".PadRight(term.Length)

  Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\My Documents\output.txt")
      Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\My Documents\input.txt")
          While Not sr.EndOfStream
              Dim buffer(1) As Char
              sr.Read(buffer, 0, 1)

              lastChars &= buffer(0)
              lastChars = lastChars.Remove(0, 1)

              sw.Write(buffer(0))

              If lastChars = term Then
                  sw.Write(Environment.NewLine)
              End If

          End While
      End Using
  End Using
  ```

*Note: This will not work with a Unicode file. This assume each characters are one byte.*